# Attach elastic IP to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance, but I want to attach an elastic IP to it so that if I ever have to resize the instance, the IP doesn't change.

So I allocated a new elastic IP address, but when I try to associate it with the instance, I get this error:

> Network vpc-c00973b1 is not attached to any internet gateway

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your instance is in AWS VPC (not in Classic). This VPC is not default VPC which comes with pre-attached Internet Gateway. Your VPC requires an internet gateway to communicate with outside of your VPC. i.e. that includes any destination on internet. To attach elastic IP you must attach an Internet Gateway with your VPC and add route to internet in your subnet's route table. (0.0.0.0/0 to Internet Gateway)

This guide will help you for detailed steps.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#Add_IGW_Attach_Gateway